# Why does getLocalName() return null?

Tags: java, xml

I'm loading some XML string like this:

```
Document doc = getDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
```

Later, I extract a node from this `Document`:

```
XPath xpath = getXPathFactory().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(expressionXPATH);
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

Node node = nodeList.item(0);
```

Now I want to get the local name of this node but I get `null`.

```
node.getLocalName(); // return null
```

With the debugger, I saw that my node has the following type: [DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED).

[The Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getLocalName()) states that `getLocalName()` returns `null` for this type of node.

- Why node is of type DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED and not ELEMENT_NODE?
- How to "convert" the type of the node?

Comment: How about showing a minimal but complete sample to allow us to reproduce the problem? Show us `xml` and `expressionXPATH`.

Comment: Have you used a namespace aware `DocumentBuilderFactory`?

Comment: At the very least, show the XPath expression you are using.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getLocalName() states:

> for nodes created with a DOM Level 1 method, [...] this is always null

so make sure you use a namespace aware `DocumentBuilderFactory` with `setNamespaceAware(true)`, that way the DOM is supporting the namespace aware DOM Level 2/3 and will have a non-null value for `getLocalName()`.

A simple test program

```
    String xml = "<root/>";

    DocumentBuilderFactory db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    Document dom1 = db.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

    System.out.println(dom1.getDocumentElement().getLocalName() == null);

    db.setNamespaceAware(true);

    Document dom2 = db.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

    System.out.println(dom2.getDocumentElement().getLocalName() == null);
```

outputs

```
true
false
```

so (at least) the local name problem you have is caused by using a DOM Level 1, not namespace aware document (builder factory).

Comment: How to know which DOM Level is in use?

Comment: If you want to query your existing implementation, you need to look into https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/DOMImplementation.html#hasFeature(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String) to test the various supported features. But I am not entirely sure how precise that is, I only know that for meaningful XPath use the namespace aware DOM is essential.